# Counting and labeling how many times the same react component has been appeared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Assume I have these grandchildren components:

GrandchildOne.tsx

```js
import React from "react";

const GrandchildOne = () => {
  const label = ? // get the index

  return <>One: {label}</>
}

export default GrandchildOne;
```

GrandchildTwo.tsx

```js
import React from "react";

const GrandchildTwo = () => {
  const label = ? // get the index

  return <>Two: {label}</>
}

export default GrandchildTwo;
```

Then a child component:

```js
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  selector: boolean[];
}

const Child = (props: Props) => {
  // something

  return
    <>
      Child component: <br />
      props.selector[0] ? <GrandchildOne /> : null
      <br />
      props.selector[1] ? <GrandchildTwo /> : null
      <br />
    </>
}

export default Child;
```

And the parent component:

App.tsx

```js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  // something

  return
    <>
      <Child selector={[false,true]}/> // shows 1
      foobar <br />
      <Child selector={[true,true]/> // shows 2
    </>
}

export default App;
```

I want this to render as this:

```
Child component:

Two: 1
foobar
Child component:
One: 1
Two: 2
```

How can I let the grandchildren components show the label that indicates the index of the component in a parent component?
I cannot pass props to the grandchildren components or child component manually.

I suppose `useRef` could be the key, but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Seems like a problematic design

Comment: How does it seem so?